# What is an idiom for being engaged in something?

Tags: phrase-requests, idiom-requests

I am looking for an idiom to express someone is completely engaged in or busy with an activity.

For example,

> When all my peers were busy preparing for the upcoming exam, I had to assist my mother in the shop.

Is there an idiomatic expression that expresses the **"busy doing something . . ."** part to emphasize the peers were solely busy with their exam preparations and could not think of doing anything else?

Answer (score 2):

While I was **knee-deep** in research, working to improve my answer, everyone else was out celebrating the new year.

From Merriam Webster, **[knee-deep](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/knee-deep)**:

> b: deeply engaged or occupied
>
> knee-deep in work

A tangible metaphor for how involved one can get in the work, to be "knee-deep" in something means the depth your involvement is significant enough that you can't be pulled away too easily.  You're not necessarily "in over your head" yet ([Lexico](https://www.lexico.com/definition/be_in_over_one%27s_head)), but it's keeping you quite occupied, and you're too busy to be pulled away just now.

For your example,
"My peers were knee-deep in exam preparation with no time to help out in the shop."

Answer (score 1):

I would have answered your question earlier but I was so wrapped up in my New Year breakfast.

> wrapped up in: idiom
>
> Definition of *wrapped up in*:
>
> fully involved or interested in (something)
> ”I was (completely) wrapped up in my work, so I didn't hear you.”
>
> [Merriam Webster](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/wrapped%20up%20in)

Answer (score 1):

Be ***[immersed in something](https://www.google.com/amp/s/www.macmillandictionary.com/amp/dictionary/british/immersed-in-something)*** is an idiomatic expression that may convey the meaning you are looking for:

> if you are immersed in something, you spend most of your time doing it or thinking about it as in:

> - David was deeply immersed in student politics.

(Macmillan Dictionary )

Answer (score 0):

There are many expressions that convey *busy doing something*, but I prefer this one— specifically because the context at hand relates to *preparing for upcoming exams.*

**[Burn the midnight oil](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/amp/english/burn-the-midnight-oil)**